# Mvc .Net.Mail: How to send email with image (logo)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mail

I am using three classes to send email but i cant to combine text email with image, or just to send image. When i get email i see empty image.
Help me to change my code so i can to send email with:

1. text
2. image
3. and style

   ```
      public class SendService : IDistributionProvider
    {
      public int Send(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument recipientsData, string subject, string fromName, string fromAccount)
   {
       foreach (XElement element in recipientsData.Root.Elements())
       {
           string email = element.Element("email").Value;
           string name = element.Element("name").Value;
           string message = element.Element("message").Value;

           bool result = EmailUtils.SendEmail(fromAccount, fromName, email, name, subject, message.Replace("\n", "<br/>"));
       }

       return 1;
   }


   public interface IDistributionProvider
   {
   int Send(XDocument recipientsData, string subject, string fromName, 
    string fromAccount);
   }


   public static class EmailUtils
   {
    private static string sendHostName;
    private static int sendPort;
    private static string userName;
    private static string password;
    private static string defaultFromEmail;
    private static string defaultFromName;

    static EmailUtils()
    {
       sendHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendHostName"];
       sendPort = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendPort"]);
       defaultFromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromEmail"];
       defaultFromName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromName"];

       string credential = Utils.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["credential"]);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(credential) && credential.Split(";".ToCharArray()).Length > 1)
       {
           userName = credential.Split(";".ToCharArray())[0];
           password = credential.Split(";".ToCharArray())[1];
       }
   }

   public static bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string toName, string subject, string body)
   {
       return SendEmail(defaultFromEmail, defaultFromName, toEmail, toName, subject, body);
   }

   public static bool SendEmail(string fromEmail, string fromName, string toEmail, string toName, string subject, string body)
   {
       try
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEmail))
           {
               return false;
           }

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toName))
           {
               toName = toEmail.Substring(0, toEmail.IndexOf("@"));
           }

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEmail))
           {
               fromEmail = defaultFromEmail;
           }

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromName))
           {
               fromName = defaultFromName;
           }

           Message message = new Message();
           message.Charset = "UTF-8";
           message.Subject = Codec.RFC2047Encode(subject, "UTF-8");
           message.From = new Address(fromEmail, fromName);
           message.To.Add(toEmail, toName);
           message.BodyHtml.Format = BodyFormat.Html;
           message.BodyHtml.Charset = "UTF-8";
           message.BodyHtml.Text = body;

           return ActiveUp.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendSsl(message, sendHostName, sendPort, userName, password, SaslMechanism.Login);
       }
       catch
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

In this way I send email- just text:

```
 string bodyEmail = "<h2>Welcome to website</h2></br><div><p>Thank for using website</p></div>";

        EmailUtils.SendEmail("xxx@gmail.com","xxxx","Contact",bodyEmail);
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it is to inline your images using [Data URIs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

You essentially inline the image into the HTML of your message.  Just follow the format

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64]
```

where mime-type may be image/jpeg, charset should be ASCII, and the bytes of the image converted to base64.  You can get that by reading the bytes of the image file from disk

```
byte[] imaeg = File.ReadAllBytes("nekkedladies.jpg");
```

then [convert the byte array to a base 64 string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var base64Imaeg = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imaeg);
```

slap it together and stick it in your html (stolen from wiki)

> <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
>   AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
>   9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Nekkid Ladies" />

btw, the example image data isn't nekkid ladies.  It's this:

[image: nekked ladies]
sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've actually ran into this same problem and what really helped me was [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/326346/How-to-embed-a-image-in-email-body). In my case I had the html and I had to parse it out using [HtmlUtilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I would not recommend using the encoded string as It is not [fully supported](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email), and it makes your message bloated. The cid way is also how outlook adds images to an email. I'd add code but I think the example was good enough in my case.